# Android - Database SQLite - convert boolean values

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design, android-listview

I am working on an Android project with a SQLite database and have a column in the database consisting of a boolean value (which store 1s and 0s) of whether an individual in the database is important.

What I am trying to do is output into a textview listview a "!" if an individual is important, and " " if they are not important using a cursor and cursor adaptor. I can get the "1" and "0"s to appear in the listview, but my question is how/where do I convert these to "!" and " "?

The query I am currently using is

```
return database.query("people", new String[] {"_id", "important"}, null, null, null, null, "important" + " DESC, " + "name"  + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this in the database query.
The `query` function is too inflexible for that, so you have to use `rawQuery` instead:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, " +
                   "CASE WHEN important THEN '!' ELSE ' ' END AS important " +
            "FROM people " +
            "ORDER BY important DESC, name ASC", null);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for logic, but the Listviews are still showing the 0s and 1s

This is what I am using: `return database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, important, " +
               "CASE WHEN important THEN important = '*' ELSE ' ' END AS impMarker " +
        "FROM people " +
        "ORDER BY important DESC, people ASC", null);`

I have tried alternating 'important=', '==' but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you change the query string? If you need a result column named `important`, change the `AS`.

Comment: Do you mean the first bit when I used `SELECT _id, important, `? When I did not put important in this (as the query you gave me), the program crashed on startup because in my other code I have `String[] from = new String[] { "important" };` to use for my CursorAdaptor

Comment: You did no mention the `CursorAdapter` in the question. Anyway, the column names must match; you could either have used `impMarker` in the `from` array, or renamed the `CASE` expression to `important` (as it's now).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a custom ListView which I am pretty sure it is, then you'll have to do that in your CustomAdapter for the ListView, which takes care of populating the ListView with the data you pass to it.[Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view) this out.
Doing it is pretty simple, just loop through your Cursor and do if else statement.